# Rails - Cannot Access Table Field

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm kind of new in rails and I have a problem I cannot solve.

I have a model Recipe

```
  class Recipe < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :items, :dependent => :destroy
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :items,**
```

and a model Item

```
  class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :recipe
  end
```

And I'm having problems accessing Item attributes through `Recipe.Example`:

I have a item (`@i`) with a description field with a string `"test_"` and `id = 1`

And I have a Recipe (`@r`) with `id=2` and description `"test_recipe"`;

I'm able to associate correctly the item to the recipe using

```
@i.recipe_id = 2
```

And if I do `@i`, I have the result

```
#<Recipe id: 2, description: "test_recipe", created_at: "2012-04-14 15:11:00", updated_at: "2012-04-14 15:11:00"`
```

But if I do `@r.items`, I have the result

`Item id: 1,recipe_id: 2,  updated_at: "2012-04-14 15:11:00" , description: nil)`

He cant access the description field of items. Why? And this is avoiding me to build a proper form for recipes cause rails doesn't build the items field.

Comment: It would be easier if you could paste your actual code rather than a summary of it.  Also I would highly recommend using variable names item and recipe rather than i and r (for code readability and maintainability).

Comment: Please format your code using backticks or 4-space indentation. This is almost unreadable.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess this is because you're attempting to do something like this:

```
@recipe.items.description
```

When, if you just want the description of each of the items:

```
@recipe.items.map(&:description)
```

Comment: In the last bit of code they show the item with a nil value in the description field.  I am not sure you are right that this is the problem.  As for what the problem is... nobody will know without some refactoring of the question.

Comment: but why cant i access the items fields (except the recipe_id) with @recipe.items ?